# PHP MySql Select statement not working... Any advice?

Tags: php, mysql

[UPDATED] with new code "sql_real_escape_string()"
[UPDATED] if anyone wants to look at the site its at  [Test site](http://synix.co.uk/beta/stanmoreform/) 
[UPDATED] with the while code showing any results via echo

Hello All,

I have looked at many posts on this matter, but simply cannot understand why the following code doesn't work:

```
    $username = $_POST['username'];

    // get the record of the user, by looking up username in the database.  
    $query = sprintf("SELECT UserName, Password FROM userlogin WHERE UserName='%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($username));

    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or 
        die ("Error Querying Database for: " . $query . 
        "<br />Error Details: " . mysql_error() . "<br/>" . $result);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
         Echo($row['UserName']);
}
```

The Code seems to be correct... the database is working perfectly (for input purposes) and the connection is a shared connection applied with require_once('databaseconnection.php'); that is working for the registration side of things.

like normal I'm sure this is something simple that I have overlooked but cannot for the life of me see it!

I do not get any error messages from the myssql_error() its simply blank.

any help would be much appreciated.

Regards

Comment: What do you get when you echo $query?  Do you get a valid sql statement?

Comment: also, it might help to show a few more lines of code where you are trying to echo what you find in the database. You can also change the query to `query = "SELECT UserName, Password FROM userlogin WHERE UserName=$username";` and it might be a good idea to sanitise the username post variable by using `$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);`

Comment: The code i get from the from echo $query is " SELECT UserName, Password FROM userlogin WHERE UserName=PCH " PCH being the variable username i entered. I have since changed the $query to `code` $query = sprintf("SELECT UserName, Password FROM userlogin WHERE UserName='%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($username));  but still no luck

Comment: Can you post how you are reading the results from $data?

Comment: At the moment I was going to print it screen using 

`code` while($item == mysqli_fetch_array($data))
       {
           echo($item);
       }
'code'
But the code does not get that far, it "die"s when querying before getting to the while loop.

Comment: It's `mysqli_real_escape_string`, not 'sql_real_escape_string`

Comment: I assume the missing `"` from the `die()` call is a typo, and not in your live code?

Comment: yeah just a type, Updated now.

Comment: Ok I managed to overcome the issue, I am not sure how but the updated code is now in the question above! Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the username you try to query as it might be empty. Do you really use a post-request to run that script? How do you verify that it does not work? What do you do with $data after the query?

If just nothing seems to happen it is likely your query did not match any record. Check for whitespace and case of the username you are looking for.

Mind those warnings:

- Use a prepared statement or at least sql-escape any user-input before using it in sql.
- Don't use die in serious code only for debugging.

Comment: I had just updated my query to "$query = sprintf("SELECT UserName, Password FROM userlogin WHERE UserName='%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($username));" just before you posted. The $data was just a troubleshooting thing, I actually intend on making the script check for both username and passwords and if matching do A else B.

Comment: Have you checked the content of $username? Have you checked whitespaces and case for the matching string in the db? Oh and update your question with your current code please.

Comment: Updated. and Yes I have the query print out on each fail, I have copy pasted this query directly into phpmyadmin and it works as expected. I know the database is connecting properly  (a: because it doesnt die on conection and b: because I use the same share connection script in another page that adds users and works well)

Comment: Have you tried using a select without a where-clause? If that does not work, it is a deeper problem. Are you sure you are using mysqli? Have you tried closing the $dbc before using it? That should produce an error. If no error happens, then the connention-resource is bogus.

Comment: Thing is I have another page that uses the same databaseonnection from a sharescript and mysqli_query and it works fine inserting new records. I have just tried the Select statement without a where clause, and im getting the same response. I also just tied to close the database prior to connection and it throws an error which is expected.

Comment: Do you have severall instances of that db you are working on? Is it possible that you are working on an empty database because your connection-settings point to a test-db? Try mysqli_info ( $link ) after issuing your query. And try a 'describe userlogin' from php. Oh and please update the code with the part after you issue the query. How do you check for a result?

Comment: I only have 1 db so no issue there, how do I implement the 'describe userlogin' you suggest, I'm not familiar with this.

Comment: Just as a normale query. But instead writing "select a from b ..." you write "describe userlogin" which will give you a normal sql-result with one row-per table-field. What does mysqli_info say after calling it after your query?

Comment: Neither works, it hits or Die before executing the mysqli_info and the $describe = "describe userlogin"; $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $describe) also dies with nothing from mysql_error()

Comment: Try running mysqli_info before you run your query. Did you run other queries before?  What happens in your connection-script? You said you have another site running the same script...  does it run on the same machine and db?

Answer (score 2):

The `$data` will contain a result object. You need to iterate over it using something like `mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)`.

Also, you can interpolate variables directly into double quoted strings - i.e. `UserName='".$username."'"` could be written more cleanly as `UserName='$username'` rather than breaking out of the string.

Also, please sanitize your input - all input is evil - using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` function. You've got a SQL injection exploit waiting to happen here.

Bear in mind that it's a very good idea to validate all data to be inserted into a database.

Comment: Thanks I have changed the query to use mysql_real_escape_string(). I have a while() loop to go through any data that is returned, should only 1 record, but just incase.

Comment: Something like `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { }` will do the trick.

Comment: If it's only one record, include `LIMIT 1` at the end of the SQL statement. It'll stop the DB engine after it finds the first result. You could in this case change the above code to an `if` statement rather than a `while` loop - makes a little bit more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Very often you have problems with query itself, not implementation. Try it in phpMyAdmin first and see if there are any problems.
Check server logs.

BY THE WAY: Never put variables from POST to query! That's definitely a SQL injection'

Comment: Thanks I have changed the query to use mysql_real_escape_string(). Also PHPmyadmin runs the copy pasted query output, perfectly as expected...

Answer (score 1):

You might have some issue with the query.
Have you Tried to echo the $query and run that directly with mysql client or workbench?

Comment: Yes I have tried the query, and it seems to be fine when copy paste direct into phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 1):

Try printing `$data` variable instead of printing only query. Check, whether you are able to get any error messages. If you could see any data then you should use mysql fetch function to iterate things. Try it.

Comment: I actually just tried that and its empty, I suppose I would expect it to be since the query is "die"ing...

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code seems ok. That is, if $dbc contains an actual database connection. But the choice of naming that variable `$data` while the function actually returns a result object or a boolean, indicates that you may process the data wrong.

If that is not the problem, we'll definately have to see more code.

Comment: yeah the $data thing was just through tweaking i copy-pasted code that I knew worked to try and trouble shoot. no dice.

Comment: also I know $dbc is working as its a shared script using Require_once(); and is working perfectly in other scripts.